# Como puedo recibir bien el formato de una fecha sacada de un <input> por POST

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo un formulario en el que pido al usuario que añada su fecha de nacimiento, pero al leer el valor que me devuelve me sale "on".

```
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
echo($edad);
```

El formulario es así:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
<input type="date" id="edad" name="edad" value="" required>
<button type="submit" id="ab">Acabar registro</button>
</form>
```

Adjunto una captura con el resultado que me sale al hacer el `echo();`
[image: WEB_FOTO]

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener la fecha en un formato que pueda enviar luego a la base de datos SQL

Comment: No se parece prácticamente en nada el código de formulario con la pantalla que muestras, ¿no? Da la sensación de que hay algún tipo de datepicker o selector de fecha asociado al campo edad, que ya debería ponerte la edad en el formato adecuado. Si dejas escribir la edad también en el input directamente, deberías validar que el formato es correcto antes de enviar el formulario a la página PHP, o validarlo en la página PHP antes de realizar la inserción.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);`? ¿Por qué en la pregunta aparece `echo();` y no `echo $edad;`?